# ¿Cómo leer con python todos los archivos de un directorio uno a uno?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi idea es crear una lista de listas donde cada sublista sea lo que extraje de cada archivo. Ejemplo: La primera sublista lo que extraje del archivo 1, la segunda sublista lo que extraje del archivo 2 y así sucesivamente. Aquí les dejo el código, el problema está en que siempre me concatena las listas como una sola:

```
for nombre_archivo_en_ruta in archivosConRuta:
    archivoCargado=cargarArchivos(nombre_archivo_en_ruta,'r')
    lista_oraciones = buscaPalabra("@",archivoCargado)
    expresion = []  # Lista para almacenar las palabras que cumplen con la expresion regular
    for nombres in lista_oraciones:  # Buscar en la lista de oraciones que tienen "@" la aparicion de la expresion regular
        expresion.append(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]{4,13}', nombres))

    lista_nombres = []
    lista_nombre_auxiliar=[]
    for hacer_lista in expresion:
        lista_nombres = lista_nombres + hacer_lista

    expresion2 = re.findall('\A\w+', archivoCargado[0])
    print(lista_nombres)
```

Comment: Deberias mostrar como estas intentado leer los archivos y asi ayudarte a corregir tu problema. Te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: ... así como también mostrar algunas líneas de ejemplo de tu archivo, aclarando qué estás intentando que coincida y el resultado esperado

Comment: Como te han dicho, sería necesario ver cómo intentas hacerlo para señalarte qué puede estar mal. De forma general, si el código que te procesa un archivo te funciona, lo que has de hacer es llamar a ese código en bucle, un archivo en cada iteración. Para iterar por los archivos de una carpeta puede serte útil `os.listdir()`, y para iterar recursivamente por todas las subcarpetas que pueda contener, `os.walk()`.

Comment: El problema es solamente en la generación de las listas? Es decir, está coincidiendo con lo que estás buscando en todos los casos? Para qué estás usando la `expresion2`?

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción, aprendida en Udacity, que me parece muy práctica, es la siguiente

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

""" Acepta un nombre de símbolo como una cadena y devuelve la ruta al archivo CSV correspondiente, 
asumiendo que se almacena en el directorio "./Ficheros_Yahoo"."""
def symbol_to_path(symbol, base_dir="./Ficheros_Yahoo"):
    """Return CSV file path given ticker symbol."""
    return os.path.join(base_dir, "{}.csv".format(str(symbol)))

def get_data(symbols):
    # Definir un rango de fechas
    dates = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2018-12-31')
    """Read stock data (adjusted close) for given symbols from CSV files."""
    # Hacemos las fechas índices del df.
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    # añadir Iberdrola como referencia, si no existe en symbols, en la posición 0
    if 'Iberdrola' not in symbols:  
        symbols.insert(0, 'Iberdrola')

    for symbol in symbols:
        #Leer y unir las cotizaciones de cada símbolo
        # Usar la función  symbol_to_path   para conseguir los ficheros .csv
        df_temp = pd.read_csv("./Ficheros_Yahoo/{}.csv".format(symbol),index_col = "Date",
                              parse_dates = True, usecols = ["Date", "Adj Close"], na_values = ["nan"])

        # Renombrar la coluamna Close con el nombre del symbol
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns = {"Adj Close":symbol})

        # Añadir los datos del nuevo dataframe
        df = df.join(df_temp)  # por defecto how = "left" , con inner elimina filas con NaN       
        """ Elimina filas con NaN en las columnas incluidas en la lista """
        if symbol == 'Iberdrola':   
            df = df.dropna(subset = ['Iberdrola'])                     
    return df

def test_run():
    # Símbolos elegidos para la importación de datos
    symbols = ['Iberdrola', 'Telefonica', 'Renta_4']  

    # Llamada a la función que consigue los datos
    df = get_data(symbols)
    return df

""" Asegura que el código que sigue a esta línea solo se ejecutará si usted
ejecute el script directamente, en lugar de importarlo para usarlo en otro programa (parte de su).
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = test_run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho intentarlo logre dar con la respuesta, sucede que estaba sobrescribiendo  la variable donde almacenaba la lista. La solución me quedó de esta forma

```
for nombre_archivo_en_ruta in archivosConRuta:
archivoCargado=cargarArchivos(nombre_archivo_en_ruta,'r')
lista_oraciones = buscaPalabra("@",archivoCargado)
expresion.clear()
 # Lista para almacenar las palabras que cumplen con la expresion regular
for nombres in lista_oraciones:  # Buscar en la lista de oraciones que tienen "@" la aparicion de la expresion regular

    expresion.append(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]{4,13}', nombres))

#print(expresion)
lista_nombres = []


for hacer_lista in expresion:
    #lista_nombres.append(hacer_lista)
    lista_nombres=lista_nombres+hacer_lista


expresion2 = re.findall('\A\w+', archivoCargado[0])
#print(lista_nombres)

#print(len(lista_nombres))
#print(expresion2)

#if (len(expresion2)==i):
    #expresion2+lista_nombres
listaX.append(lista_nombres)
lista_oraciones.clear()
lista_nombre_paquetes.append(expresion2)

# print(listaX)
# print(lista_nombre_paquetes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero haber entendido bien tu pregunta.

El setup:

Tengo 3 archivos con diferentes nombres pero todos contienen una variación de este texto:

```
Contenido del archivo1
Lo que no quiero que aparezca // Juan Perez tragaba trigo en un trigal Jorge Ramirez
Lo que no quiero que aparezca Manuel Lopez
Fin archivo1
```

El código:

```py
import os
import re
# La siguiente notacion es para Windows, el punto significa "en esta carpeta", donde se esta ejecutando python
CARPETA = '.\\Carpeta\\'

listArc = os.listdir(CARPETA)
listFinal = []

for archivo in listArc:
    with open(CARPETA+archivo) as fo:
        f = fo.readlines()
        f = '\n'.join(f)
        print(f)
        if re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]{4,13}', f) != []:
            listFinal.append(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]{4,13}', f))

print(listFinal)
```

Y el print resultante sería:

```
[['Juan Perez', 'Jorge Ramirez', 'Manuel Lopez'], ['Juan Perez', 'Jorge Ramirez', 'Manuel Lopez'], ['Juan Perez', 'Jorge Ramirez', 'Manuel Lopez']]
```

Primero la lista principal, que es todo lo que el programa recorre, y luego la lista a nivel de cada línea de archivo.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
lista_de_archivos = os.listdir(ruta_de_la_carpeta)
```

Capaz te sirve.
Saludos.

Comment: import glob
lista_de_archivos = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Joaquin\\Documents\\Zoom\\plmnrc7_Nokia3g\\*.xml')
print(lista_de_archivos) Funciona mejor ese y es con filtro acordate de instalar la libreria glob

Comment: Joaquin, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. Recuerde que en cualquier momento puedes [edit] tus publicaciones.

Comment: Las respuestas con solo código tienden a ser consideradas de baja calidad. Por favor lee [answer], edita tu respuesta y agrega una explicación de cómo tu código resuelve el problema. Un saludo.